# Handling boolean data returned by JSON string using angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am reading data from a JSON string using angular and playing around with my app at the moment.

```
Task Status : {{task.completed}}  // displays true or false
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
if(task.completed == true) print "completed";
else "print Not completed"
```

How can this be done in an angular expression?

Comment: You can use ng-if to get this done....

Comment: angular 1 or 2? you could have an Angular2 <element *ngIf="task.completed"> or *ngIf="!task.completed". Or, for Angular 1, you could have ng-if="task.completed"/ng-if="!task.completed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for it

```
<div> Task Status : 
 <span ng-if="task.completed">{{"completed"}}</span 
 <span ng-if="!task.completed">{{"print Not completed"}}</span 
</div>
```

Also @Satpal answer is really helpfull

Answer (score 7):

You can use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in view like

```
Task Status : {{task.completed ? "completed" : "print Not completed"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If print means simply showing a label then this can be done like this example below..

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          {{names}}
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Js code will be

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var myCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
           $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
      .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
    }
```